# Crop Image Before Upload

Tags: javascript, php, image, upload

I have this code:

```
<form method="post" action="postoffer.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false">

                    <label for="image">Select Image: </label>
                    <input type="file"  name="image" accept="image/*"capture>

                    <input type="submit" value="Send!" name="send">
</form>
```

I need to crop the image uploaded before passing it to "postoffer.php".

I don't need to show the user it has been cropped. I just want to crop say 20% top and bottom for example.

Is there a javascript way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Because I have a bandwidth limit

Comment: You can use the benefits of canvas for this : http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-crop/